# App scheme (ex.twitter://) doesn't work in android firefox browser

Tags: android, deep-linking

Deeplink app scheme (ex.twitter://) doesn't work in Android Firefox browser it getting error page

Comment: Did you see this? https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/977330

Comment: Its works fine in latest firefox browser version (27.0, 28.0 beta)