# Android deep link Firefox like Chrome

Tags: firefox, android-intent, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I have an unclaimed bounty for this question.  If someone is able to provide a working answer that meets my criteria, I will reward them with the bounty.  It’s not visible because the bounty expired, but I can reward it after the fact to an acceptable answer.

My app has intent filters set up that work as desired when I use Chrome.  Unfortunately, Firefox does not implement deep links the same way.  When I tap a link in Firefox, it shows a little Android icon at the end of the address bar.  If I tap that, it will open my app *in Firefox* and I don't like this behavior.  With Chrome, it simply opens the app (after prompting you to choose the app the first time)

*UPDATE: singletask **does not work** and it has the heinous side effect of the [resuming activity not being able to get the extras from the intent that launched it.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42209513/3634990)*

This is not a duplicate of other deep link Firefox questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289586/open-android-app-from-url-using-intent-filter-not-working), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21676680/app-scheme-ex-twitter-doesnt-work-in-android-firefox-browser), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872378/app-deep-linking-not-supported-on-latest-firefox-for-android-36-0), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407300/redirect-from-mozilla-firefox-to-android-app-deep-linking), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019182/android-intent-filter-not-launching-app-from-browser?rq=1), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289586/open-android-app-from-url-using-intent-filter-not-working?rq=1), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966190/firefox-for-android-does-not-launch-app-when-link-is-clicked?rq=1))  because those questions are about how to get deep links to work *at all* whereas I understand how deep links work in Firefox and **they already work for me**, but I want to change the behavior...

I'm asking: **How, if possible, can I open the existing instance of my app via deep link from Firefox and have it behave the same way that it does with Chrome?**  I don't want use an iframe.

I have implemented http and https intent filters, like so:

```
<!-- https -->
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
      android:host="myappurl"
      android:pathPrefix="/myprefix"
      android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
<!-- http -->
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data
        android:host="myappurl"
        android:pathPrefix="/myprefix"
        android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

If you're going to provide a solution, please provide a clear example that includes context as to where the code should go in the manifest (if at all), and what the side effects are (see my link above- singletask does not work for this)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `android:launchMode="singleTask"` under your activity tag.

This prevents opening multiple instances. If your app is already open it will launch it, else it will create a new instance.

Comment: I have tested this and it does not work.  Also, **all intent extras will be null if singletask is used** and this is a dealbreaker for me.

Comment: You are correct that the intent extras are null, I'm currently trying to solve this.